# How do I open a Markup-list on a new screen?

Tags: roku, brightscript

From BrightScript, how do I open the following MarkUplist on a new screen (not the Main screen/scene)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<component name="SimpleMarkupListScene" extends="Group" >
<script type="text/brightscript" uri="pkg:/components/screens/SimpleMarkupListScene.brs" />

<children>

  <MarkupList
   id="SimpleMarkupList"
   itemComponentName="details_screen"
   itemSize="[500, 50]"
   itemSpacing="[0, 20]"
   translation = "[ 1325, 175 ]" />

</children> 
</component>
```

Comment: The question is unclear, please provide more details about what are You trying to achieve? Would You like to add "MarkupList" to a different brightscript component/view?

Answer (score 2):

You can set up observer on `itemSelected` field of SimpleMarkUpList.

```
m.SimpleMarkupList = m.top.findNode("SimpleMarkupList")
m.SimpleMarkupList.observeField("itemSelected", "onItemSelected")
```

Create `onItemSelected` callback:

```
sub onItemSelected()
 itemIndex = m.SimpleMarkuplist.itemSelected
 m.SimpleMarkuplist.content.getChild(itemIndex)
end sub
```

You have now fetched item da user selected, from here You can check the id if this item and decide would You like to open/create a new View with: `m.NewViewName = createObject("roSGNode", "NewViewName")` and append it to the top: `m.top.append(m.NewViewName)` or if You already created the view just show it with `m.NewViewName.visible = true.`

Answer (score 0):

You said you can try to open a markup-up list in another scene. Without any action not Jump to another Scene. @U.mitic Answer is right But. That condition you use two scenarios Like below.

**First Scenario:**
You Can Visible = false for another component and only display a Markup List. Here you only visible markup list on the main screen. First Scenario I Write For Only Understanding. It's a working But Bad Practice to Good Developing.

**Second Scenario:**
That scenario you required for another component Like Button. Here press ok on that component to jump markup list.
@U.Mitic Answer is directly you access markup grid as a child.